# Copying Data in Excel and replacing in Word Document using UIPATH

Tags: uipath

I would like to copy data from excel and replace text in word document.

However the cell references that contain data are NOT fixed as it depends on the number of debtors and the number of table rows the user wants.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can try reading the excel data using Read Range Activity and then Lookup into that datatable for the exact values that you want to replace.

And you can use read the Word File and replace the required values in Word file from the Datatable.